# How do you make .load load a file that isn't index.php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this .load js function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    id = getUrlVars();
    $("#customers").load("/search", {id: id['id']});
});
```

Under the views the structure looks like this
quote/customers/search.php & quote/customers/index.php

index.php is called and is suppose to render search.php inside of the customers div, but it infinitely calls index.php instead. I've tried 'search', '/search', 'customers/search', '/customers/search', and tried putting '.php' on the end of all those sequences. Why in the world is it calling the index file and not the search file?

Comment: Why haven't you specified "search.php"?

Comment: if you have a directory named "search" in the root, the url you have provided is targeting that directory. Then, your webserver sees that you haven't specified a file within that directory to target, so it goes to the configured default file, which in this case is index.php. So that url targets "/search/index.php", assuming you aren't using a .htaccess to rewrite the url.

Comment: @Blazemonger As stated above, I tried that.

Comment: No redirection server side?!

Comment: You tried `/quote/customers/search.php` right?

Comment: @KevinB That's enlightening but even if I make it "quote/customers/search.php" it still targets index.php. Is there something I'm missing from what you've said?

Comment: That means you're doing something server-side that's changing the url, such as using a .htaccess file, or a web.config if using iis.

Comment: Well, the only thing in the .htaccess file is "deny from all". I thought the framework might have been causing this earlier. Know anything I could grep for to narrow my search? It seems clear I'm going to have to do this another way, but I'm dumbfounded by why this is happening and want to know why now.